# Save image in internal storage without compressing

Tags: android, storage

I am saving an image in storage, but the quality of image is lost due to compression. So how could I save the image without compressing it.
I'm using the following code

```
//Creating bitmap from Resource id
Bitmap bitmap=BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), BitmapId);
    String extStorage=Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();

    File file = new File(extStorage, "name.png");
    if(file.exists())
        file.delete();
    try {
        outStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, outStream);
.....
}
```

Please let me know how to save the image without losing its quality..

Answer (score 0):

The second parameter u supply 100 is actually does not affect ur image quality,but in case if u want to compress more u can reduce the value to even 10 ,u will get a low quality image in that case ,only useful for memory issues,,

But i thing the value 100 will not affect ur quality, its just a guess

Comment: I want to save the original image, not the compressed one. The quality parameter is ignored for PNG compression, but then even the saved image is compressed and hence its quality is affected. What should i do to retain the original image